# How to interpolate points while taking their weights into account?

Tags: python, math, interpolation

I'm trying to write a Python function which does the following:

1. Takes in an array of points where each point has:

   - Position from 0 to 1 (x)
   - Weight (w)
2. Smoothly interpolates between them in such a way that point weights are taken into account.

To make it more clear, here's an illustration:

---

[image: 1]

---

Notice how points with weights are "pushing" other points around.

Comment: Your question lacks details: what is f(x) (I assume it's the new value of x, but you don't say that) ? And more importantly, exactly how are the weights taken into account ?

Comment: Why are they pushed that way? Why does w=0 push anything at all? Why is the last example symmetric even though the weights are not!?

Comment: @luk2302: I was about to ask the exact same question about the symmetry!

Comment: @Swifty `f(x)` is a new value of `x` indeed.

I unfortunately don't know how to describe how weights are taken into account better than with that illustration. I guess weights should impact the "speed" with which f(x) changes as we go from x = 0 to x = 1.

There is no need to care about the symmetry of the illustration, it's just an artistic approximation.

Comment: But how do you want to implement the calculation if you don't know the rules ?

Comment: @luk2302 w=0 means that a point is not contributing to the "pushing" of other points. I'm not sure, but maybe the CSS Flexbox is a good mental model of this?

Comment: @Swifty That's exactly why I'm on a website where people ask questions. I'm basically describing an approximation of what should happen in hopes that someone may know a proper method that is close enough to give something similar to this.

Comment: Hi! This is a very interesting question. I do have one question though: how did you arrive at the exact values of f(x) that you arrived at on these images? If you can explain that, it would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a physics model that slowly moves the points around as if they were sliding magnets.

At each iteration, the force exerted on each magnet is calculated, and the magnet moves accordingly.

The repulsion exerted by a magnet over another magnet is proportional to the inverse of the square of the distance between the two, because that's how it works for actual magnets.

```py
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  ## uncomment those lines for graphics output

def move_points(weights, points=None, left=0, right=1, n_iter = 1000, learning_rate = 0.0001):
    n = weights.shape[0]
    if not points:
        points = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
    assert(points.shape == weights.shape == (n,))
    #plt.scatter(points, [0]*n)
    for t in range(1, n_iter+1):
        dists = (points - points.reshape((n,1)))
        coeffs = np.sign(dists) / dists**2
        forces = np.nansum(weights*coeffs, axis=1)
        points = points - learning_rate * forces
        points[0] = max(left, points[0])
        points[-1] = min(points[-1], right)
        #plt.scatter(points, [t]*n)
    #plt.show()
    return points
```

Testing:

```py
for weights in map(np.array, ([0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,2], [1,0,10,0,2])):
    print('weights: ', weights)
    print('points:  ', move_points(weights, n_iter=100))
    print()

# weights:  [0 0 0 0 0]
# points:   [0.   0.25 0.5  0.75 1.  ]

# weights:  [1 0 0 0 2]
# points:   [0.         0.32732937 0.46804381 0.59336546 1.        ]

# weights:  [ 1  0 10  0  2]
# points:   [0.         0.11141358 0.46804381 0.83729092 1.        ]
```

Graphics output of trajectories:

[image: weights = [0 0 0 0 0]]
Weights = [0 0 0 0 0]

[image: weights = [1 0 0 0 2]]
Weights = [1 0 0 0 2]

[image: weights = [1 0 10 0 2]]
Weights = [1 0 10 0 2]

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to make up a rule, for instance:

> The distance between two adjacent points should be proportional to the sum of their weights.

This rule does not seem perfectly consistent with your examples. In your examples, it looks like every point repulses every other point, not just adjacent points.

But it has the advantage of being a simple rule.

Here is an implementation of this rule in python:

```py
from itertools import pairwise, accumulate

def place_points(weights):
    if all(w == 0 for w in weights):
        return [p / (len(weights)-1) for p in range(0, len(weights))]
    else:
        dists = [w1+w2 for w1,w2 in pairwise(weights)]
        positions = list(accumulate(dists, initial=0))
        total_dist = positions[-1]
        normalised_positions = [p / total_dist for p in positions]
        return normalised_positions

for weights in ([0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,2], [1,0,10,0,2]):
    print('weights: ', weights)
    print('points:  ', place_points(weights))
    print()

# weights:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
# points:   [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]

# weights:  [1, 0, 0, 0, 2]
# points:   [0.0, 0.333, 0.333, 0.333, 1.0]

# weights:  [1, 0, 10, 0, 2]
# points:   [0.0, 0.043, 0.478, 0.913, 1.0]
```